# Unable to view changed text within WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, browser, text, replace

I'm trying to change/filter the text within my `WebBrowser` control, but it doesn't appear to be working.

Here's the code I've tried:

```
   private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
       webBrowser1.DocumentText.Replace("10.86.190.30","KM");   
    }
```

At first I thought the `DocumentCompleted` event wasn't firing, so I assigned it to a button click I could manually trigger, but even then, it did not change on the browser control.

I've tried looking for others with the issue, but all I can find are questions on changing text *size* or *font*, not the **text itself**.

Is anyone able to identify where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing a replace then throwing away the result.  `String.Replace` doesn't modify the original string, it returns an updated string.  You'll need to use:

```
webBrowser1.DocumentText = webBrowser1.DocumentText.Replace("10.86.190.30","KM");
```

Comment: Ah, you're right. Thank you for the explanation and result :) I'll mark as acp in a few!